# SCORM 1.2 Development Tool

Tags: ide, scorm, scorm1.2

Can anyone recommend a development tool I can use to build SCORM 1.2 content? I would like to develop my SCORM content using HTML and Javascript.

From some of the examples I have seen online, all SCORM content gets rendered in Flash.

I managed to find an IDE that does what I want (http://www.scormsoft.com/trident) but it's only compatible for SCORM 2004 systems.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: SCORM utilizes a JavaScript API - that most SCO's are rendering flash is inconvenient but in no way necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from personal experience, I found the best way to build SCORM content is by not using  off-the-shelf tools. I find they are just too inflexible and render a lot of rubbish markup.

Best thing to do is download a basic [manifest template](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/content-packaging/xml-schema-definition-files/) and look at [examples](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/) from the really useful scorm.com website.

I use NetBeans as my JavaScript IDE which makes creating large SCORM content really easy.

Comment: What about the SCORM API? Trident software builds the API for you. I am not sure hwo to build a SCORM API.

Comment: The example packages from the scorm.com site will include those. All you will need to do is include the API JavaScript file and start developing. I also recommend testing your packages with SCORM Cloud (cloud.scorm.com), since that is the only was to ensure your SCORM code works.

Comment: Not having a 100% SCORM IDE is not ideal. But I think this way is achievable. Hopefully my next SCORM project will be in 2004 so I can use Trident software.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ActivePresenter](http://atomisystems.com) with AJAX output. This uses HTML/CSS/Javascript to render contents.